# iOS memory capacity

Tags: ios, memory-management

Is there a good reference somewhere for how iPhone/iPod/iPad manage memory, and how to find out how much program address space might be available on a given device?  Is it a virtual system, where virtual address space can use the storage capacity that is free for adding songs, etc.?    Are there any specs for how the different devices differ in this respect (if they do)?

Also - in a project, if there are many files, such as images, that are part of the project, but they only get looked up and loaded a few at a time, does everything in the project use up available RAM, or only whatever is loaded and not released at any time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a good reference somewhere for how iPhone/iPod/iPad manage memory

[Apple's Memory Management Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).

> how to find out how much program address space might be available on a given device

I wouldn't base any code on the available memory on a device.

> Is it a virtual system

No.

> Are there any specs for how the different devices differ in this respect

They differ in RAM size and other factors (CPU clock speed, GPU). The table [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_iOS_devices) has some details.

> if there are many files, such as images, that are part of the project, but they only get looked up and loaded a few at a time, does everything in the project use up available RAM, or only whatever is loaded and not released at any time

Only what is loaded into memory.

Comment: The reference you cited in your response is useful - but can you point me to any reference that would provide all the info in your answer, such as the questions about virtual memory and unused files in the project?

Comment: Unfortunately Jonathan there isn't any reference of the sort that I know of.

Comment: iOS does have virtual memory, but current devices have no swap file. So you're limited to the RAM on the device, but still helps with fragmentation and such.